# How do I delete my account?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

Answers, Questions, Comments, Everything....
I don't care about the points system, but when I get negative comments on the recommendations I make to help solve a problem, I'm done here.

Comment: Check http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/user-deletion

Answer (score 11):

If you have never voted and have only 1 post you can delete your account yourself from your profile. Under "Edit Profile & Settings" click "Delete Profile".

> [image: image of delete button]

You can't delete your account yourself if you have more than one post and / or you have voted on the site. If you want to delete your account after making a post or voting on other posts, you have to contact the Stack Exchange team. The moderators don't have the ability to delete or destroy accounts once they exceed a minimal reputation threshold.

To contact the Stack Exchange regarding the deletion of your account, [fill out the form](https://askubuntu.com/help/user-deletion) and submit it. You need to follow all the procedures exactly as it says. Once the team deletes your account, they will send you an email notifying you of the deletion.

You can also find the account deletion form if you click on the *Contact us* link at the bottom of the site.

See also:

- [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: I did not know where to ask this, sorry if it's wrong to do it here. If I change the username, can users see what name I had before? Is the username that appears in the comments and others also changed? Thank you.