# How can I delete my account?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete my account?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1535/how-do-i-delete-my-account)

Is it possible for a user to delete his account? If yes, how it could be done?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison It seems to me that this question (and its answer) are actually more general than [that older one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1535/how-do-i-delete-my-account). In this case, I'd suggest we make *that one* a duplicate of *this*, rather than the other way around. ([There is precedent for this.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3237/can-older-questions-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-newer-questions-in-special-circum))