# Why my account is not deleted yet?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I did the [needed steps](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4097/how-can-i-delete-my-account) to delete my account but til now it still active. Why?

Comment: Wait, if you *really* want to leave, why are you checking?

Answer (score 7):

You will need to wait for action, it is not automatically done.

Patience is the key, even for rushed actions.

Comment: Very wise, young grasshopper.